# Как растянуть по ширине одну строку текста, например заголовок, не используя text-align-last?

Tags: css

[image: Например, хочу вот такой текст]

Можно использовать text-align-last, но он много где не работает.
Можно было бы сделать вот так

```
.text{
  text-align: justify;
}
.text::after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Но блок получается слишком высоким, из-за line-height блока after и не становится меньше, если на нем это свойство ручками задать. Вижу выход в задании фиксированной высоты блоку text. Но ощущаю, что стою на костылях. Можно это сделать как-то по-красивее?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно, чтобы на любых размерах экрана заголовок был растянут во всю ширину, можно задать font-size в единицах измерения vw:

```css
h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<h1>какой-то заголовок тут висит</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я упоролся..

```js
$('.head-text').each(function(){
  WinHeader($(this));
});

function WinHeader(el){
  let text_arr = el.text().split(''),
      text_len = text_arr.length;

  el.empty();
  el.css('font-size', `calc(100vw / ${text_len})`);

  for(let i = 0; i<text_len; i++){
    el.append(`<div>${text_arr[i] === ' ' ? '&nbsp;' : text_arr[i]}</div>`);
  }
}
```

```css
.head-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.head-text > div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="head-text">Какой-то широкий заголовок</div>

<div class="head-text">Короткий заголовок</div>

<div class="head-text">Ваще</div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]